# Installing Citrix Receiver on Ubuntu 20.04 - missing libwebkitgtk-1.0.0

Tags: apt, dependencies, citrix, 20.04, icaclient

I'm trying to install Citrix on Ubuntu 20.04 and facing the following issue:

```
✓ ~/Downloads→ sudo dpkg -i icaclient_13.10.0.20_amd64.deb                                                                                                                                                                           [20:33:59]
Selecting previously unselected package icaclient.
(Reading database ... 205904 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack icaclient_13.10.0.20_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking icaclient (13.10.0.20) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of icaclient:
 icaclient depends on libwebkit-1.0-2 | libwebkitgtk-1.0-0; however:
  Package libwebkit-1.0-2 is not installed.
  Package libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package icaclient (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 icaclient
```

I couldn't find `ibwebkit-1.0-2` or `libwebkitgtk-1.0-0` in focal-fossa repos, and installing from `.deb` is not an option since these packages depend on a whole lot of other things it seems.
And of course I also have newer versions of these libraries, so I'm not sure i would be able to install the required versions even if I found all dependencies manually.

Is there any way to fix this to make Citrix work on Ubuntu 20.04? I've spent 3 days setting up my system and I don't even want to think of getting back on 18.04...

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site. For *focal fossa* [20.04] questions you'll need to use a development support site such as IRC (#ubuntu+1) or Ubuntu Forums, or wait until after release for this site (expected release date for Ubuntu 20.04 is 23rd April 2020 when your question will be on-topic here).

Comment: If you're after support you should use a #ubuntu+1 site as *focal fossa* hasn't been released yet, however if you're QA-testing and are seeking help with bug reporting, you can also use #ubuntu-quality on IRC or telegram; for help with https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: Sorry about posting on the wrong site. It was a long day... :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am on ubuntu 20.04 and the client installed deb worked fine
https://www.citrix.com/downloads/workspace-app/linux/workspace-app-for-linux-latest.html

debian -> full packages -> Citrix Workspace app for Linux (x86_64)

```
sudo dpkg -i ./icaclient_20.9.0.15_amd64.deb  # supply full path to reach this file ... here I use relative path using ./xxx else give /full/path/to/icaclient_20.9.0.15_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package icaclient.
(Reading database ... 382197 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack icaclient_20.9.0.15_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking icaclient (20.9.0.15) ...
Setting up icaclient (20.9.0.15) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.2) ...
```

You may get an interactive prompt saying :

```
Configuring icaclient
Do you want to install the app protection component ?
```

use up/down arrow keys to move selection ... pick no  then hit tab key so cursor is overtop Ok then hit enter

once installed to launch search for citrix in the ubuntu dash ( tap `WIN` key and enter citrix then choose `Citrix Workspace`) ... it launched OK

I did not need to install any dependancies however this blog shows some other steps I did not need to do  https://tech.xenit.se/how-to-install-citrix-workspace-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Thanks a lot, saved my day!
I had to add a softlink for mozilla certs to fix the SSL error, otherwise works fine.

Comment: Softlink instructions are here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CitrixICAClientHowTo#A5._Add_more_SSL_certificates
In my case I needed `sudo ln -s /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/GlobalSign_Root_CA.crt .`

Comment: thank you. It really helped. Ubuntu 20.04 user