# Citrix receiver installation error on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dependencies

I am new to Linux/Ubuntu. Trying to install Citrix workspace app in Ubuntu 20.04, but getting the below error. Tried many options but unable to resolve.

```
sakubu@sakubuntu:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i icaclient_18.8.0.31_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 187874 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack icaclient_18.8.0.31_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking icaclient (18.8.0.31) over (18.8.0.31) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of icaclient:
 icaclient depends on libwebkit-1.0-2 | libwebkitgtk-1.0-0; however:
  Package libwebkit-1.0-2 is not installed.
  Package libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package icaclient (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
```

Some dependencies are missing it says. Don't know how to resolve.
Truly appreciate your help in this regard.

Recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 in dual boot mode.

Comment: Seems related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1228614/installing-citrix-receiver-on-ubuntu-20-04-missing-libwebkitgtk-1-0-0

Comment: Using the terminal, can you share the output of apt-cache policy icaclient

Comment: yeah totally related

Comment: Did you try using the fix command in terminal ?
sudo apt --fix-broken install

Comment: This could probably fix the issue you're having. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/118782/4713

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.
I tried broken fix install.
After a long try, through this forum i was able to find a solution to atleast install successfully. 
Now i have installed it, but when i try to connect to citrix through Firefox i get the below popup when i click the launch.

"cannot connect to "0.0.0.2-RPC_DG_2SP29212"
No such file or directory.Verify your connection settings.

I get the above message when i click launch. Need help.